# Regex to grab key-value including the empty space

Tags: java, php, regex, perl, expression

I have a problem to grab value that having a space from my Regex.
Can anyone help me to provide to the correct regex with using key-value mechanisme. Please take note that the key-value position might change and does not fixed.

Regex

```
\s*([\w\d_]*)=(.*?)\s+
```

Input

```
spt=38271 deviceExternalId=SUKUK node 1 dst=99.111.185.141 app=HTTPS rt=Jan 23 2013 15:30:45 deviceFacility=Packet filter msg=Connection was reset by server destinationTranslatedPort=443
```

### My result

```
Match 1: spt=38271 
    Subgroups:
    1: spt
    2: 38271
Match 2: deviceExternalId=SUKUK 
    Subgroups:
    1: deviceExternalId
    2: SUKUK
Match 3:  dst=99.111.185.141 
    Subgroups:
    1: dst
    2: 99.111.185.141
Match 4: app=HTTPS 
    Subgroups:
    1: app
    2: HTTPS
Match 5: rt=Jan 
    Subgroups:
    1: rt
    2: Jan          **==>Should grab [Jan 23 2013 15:30:45]**
Match 6:  deviceFacility=Packet 
    Subgroups:
    1: deviceFacility
    2: Packet       **==>Should grab [Packet filter]**
Match 7:  msg=Connection 
    Subgroups:
    1: msg
    2: Connection   **==>Should grab [Connection was reset by server]**
Match 8:  destinationTranslatedPort=443 
    Subgroups:
    1: destinationTranslatedPort
    2: 443
```

Comment: Can't you have separate delimiter for the key-value pairs. As per your current text, it's not possible with regex to get the desired result. Just think, on what basis would you select `Packet filter` combined, but at the same time reject `SUKUK node` from being selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
([\w\d_]+)=(.*?)(?=\s+[\w\d_]+=|$)

print "$1\n$2";
```

Comment: It will also select `SUKUK node 1` which OP don't want.

Comment: I love this solution... but i have to do extra splitting program... but very good idea... I love it.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler: `\s*([\w\d_]*)=([^=]+)\s+`